# Any fast screenshot services available?

Tags: php, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I need one that does not have a big queue. So, if it does not have it on its cache, it would generate and deliver it reasonably fast (1-4 seconds).

I do have a list of services, what I am asking is if you have experience with any such service that meets the above criteria that you could recommend.

Thank you

Edit: To clarify my intent, I need a thumbnail of any given website approximately 200-300 px wide. I need it fast because it is to be displayed while my the script calculates carious stuff on the background (all this is done and working. I am using a free service for test but it has a huge queue and most of the time the frontend side redirects to the results before the screenshot appears. My code takes about 10 seconds before it redirects to the results usually)

Comment: I've always found the PrtSc key on my keyboard to be pretty responsive.

Comment: I think what Dominic is saying is that it's kind of hard for us to give recommendations without knowing *what you're doing* and why you're doing it.  What type of screenshots do you need?  The entire thing, or just a thumbnail?  What are you trying to do?  Preview a web page?  Check cross-browser compat?

Comment: Possibly a question for: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what is the reason of mentioning PHP tag here?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: a PHP programmer is possible to have had the same issue to implement

Comment: @john.But PHP tag here means that this question is about php, or at least covers some aspects of php, not PHP programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do something on your own you by starting an X server and taking screenshots by using "import" command -- I'm pretty sure that it's going to be faster than any external services.

Comment: This is a nice option, but I need this for a client and he does not host his site on a dedicated server. So, although a great hack to do, it 's too big a gun for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It would impossible to guarantee 1-4 seconds for any webpage, it will always depend on how fast the page and all linked resources can be delivered. If you can load and see the page in a browser in 1-4 seconds, it is possible.
I'm about to launch a webpage screenshot service that takes max 300-500ms to capture it, after the it gotten the required resources. For instances you can get a thumbnail of google in under a second. But for a instance newspaper sites tend to be slow, so loading them can take up to 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you get it launched? I'm looking for a faster service as well.

Comment: I did, www.pagelr.com, let me know if fast enough?